# javascript:history.back() and previous page refresh

Tags: javascript, refresh, history

i have the button on my page `<span id="back" class="button" onclick="location.href='javascript:history.back()';"` which works fine, but i need it to refresh the previous page. The problem is, history.back() is only acceptable way for me, window.refferer didnt help. I already trying some tricks with meta-tags, still nothing.

Comment: Can't you just pass the previous page as a query argument, like `?back=index/fr`, and then use a regular <a> link?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using HTML 5, you can use [the popstate event](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#event-definitions-0)

> The popstate event is fired in certain cases when navigating to a session history entry.

But I don't think there's a way to do this in prior versions.

The browser has no idea that you arrived at a page via `history.back()` -- there are no fired events that you could reference from javascript (prior to HTML 5)

Comment: I am using codeigniter and construction like <a href="index/fr">
<a href="index/en", thats why my document.referrer stops working after i click on lenguage selection, mb any suggestion, how can i fix this? Mb somehow deny the href to edit referrer?

Answer (score 1):

MDN: Note that the browser won't attempt to load this URL after a call to pushState()

WhatWG:
  Since this is neither a navigation of the browsing context nor a history traversal, it does not cause a hashchange event to be fired.

The case when it (popstate event) is fired may be related to current entry in the session history represents a non-GET request